# Nested function returns undefined

Tags: jquery, arrays, function

I've a function within afunction that loops through data object and returning array after
when i try to console log it its 'undefined'

```
function xyz (arg){
    var arr = [];
    function(){
        while(condition){
            arr.push(string);
        }
        return(arr);
    }
}

console.log( xyz(arg));

//undefined
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: sorry for the title i had difficulties with title restrictions

Comment: Can you give details on exactly what you're trying to achieve, as I'm 99% sure that event if this worked it isn't the best way to do it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're wrong . It is 100% wrong way to ask

Comment: @Royi I used Math.floor to be generous ;)

Comment: where `string` comes from ?

Comment: are you trying to return a function from your function, or return the result of a function?

Comment: I think you should go back to a basic tutorial about javascript. What you are doing makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: actually im using Jsom to get Sharepoint List Items
http://pastebin.com/bkNcV2ey

Comment: @AhmedAborady that does not help us answer your question.

Comment: i just wanted to simplify the code

Comment: Just the problem when to return the Arr to make sure the while loop already excuted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting undefined because there is nothing being returned from function xyz. You need to save that value.

I am assuming that inplace of condition and string there is actual condition and string variable.
So do something like this

```
function xyz (arg){
    var arr = [];
    var x = function(){
                while(condition){
                     arr.push(string);
                }
                return;
            };
    y = x(); 
    return arr;
}
console.log(xyz("xyz"));
```

Answer (score 3):

First of you dont loop through anything. There are actually a lot of tings wrong with your code:

- `arg` is unused
- `condition` is undefiend
- `string` is also undefined
- `return` is not a function, but a keyword
- the anonymous `function(){}` is never executed

i can only guess you want to do the following:

```
function xyz (arg){
    var arr = [];
    for(item in arg){
        arr.push(item);
    }
    return arg;
} //this gets all the keys from an object and puts it into a list.
```

Comment: Not to mention the nested inner function is never called

Comment: you probably want the `return` outside the `for...in`